# An intuitive explanation of the instrumental variable

Tags: causality, instrumental-variables, confounding, endogeneity, exogeneity

This is something that I had dealt with in my MSc Economics many years ago, passed the exams with flying colours, yet when I thought about it in more depth today, I was somewhat puzzled. This could perhaps be because it's been a couple of years since I last covered the topic, or maybe it is due to the fact that I had only learnt the theory and never dealt with a practical example; regardless some intuitive explanation, strengthened with a mathematical proof would be very much appreciated.

The general idea is that for $y=\beta'x+\varepsilon$, the exogeneity assumption must hold -i.e. $\mathbb{E}\{x(y-\beta'x)\}=0$. When this assumption is violated -i.e. $\mathbb{E}\{x(y-\beta'x)\}\neq0$, we find an instruments $z$, such that $\mathbb{E}\{z(y-\beta'x)\}=0$, while $\mathbb{E}\{xz\}\neq 0$. In other words, $x$ and $z$ are correlated, but while $x$ is correlated with $\varepsilon$, $z$ is not! I cannot see how this could be the case. Or does the assumption has more to do with "perfect" collinearity? As in $z$ would still be correlated with $\varepsilon$, but not to the same extent that $x$ is? Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the most intuitive explanation lies in the causal Directed Acyclic Graph (DAG) approach taken by Judea Pearl, where $A\to B$ means $A$ causes $B$. The typical setup for an instrumental variable is as follows:

[image]

Here the unmeasured variable $E$ is your variable causing the problem, because it sets up a backdoor path from $X$ to $Y,$ and is thus a true confounder. You cannot condition on it because it is unmeasured. So you find an instrumental variable $Z$ that causally affects only $X$, and has no causal effect on $E$ or $Y$ in either direction. The reason $Z$ and $E$ can be uncorrelated is that if you examine the path $Z\to X\leftarrow E,$ the collider at $X$ prevents causal information flow from $Z$ to $E.$ Similarly, if you examine the path $Z\to X\to Y\leftarrow E,$ the collider at $Y$ prevents information flow. There are no other paths from $Z$ to $E,$ so there can be no information flow from $Z$ to $E$ or vice versa.

Incidentally, it is also sometimes possible to correct for $E$ using the frontdoor approach. If you can insert a variable $Z$ in-between $X$ and $Y$ thus:

[image]

Then you can invoke the frontdoor adjustment formula:
$$P(Y|\operatorname{do}(X))=\sum_zP(Z=z|X)\,\sum_xP(Y|X=x, Z=z)\,P(X=x).$$
This is not always possible, unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

I also struggled with intuitive understanding of IV method. There are few explanations, which are worth considering. Let me present you the one I found by myself, which is for me quite convincing.

First, for me DAG paradigm perfectly described by @Adrian Keister is the key to understand what is going on here. It helps to both understand exclusion restriction assumption, as well as other variants of instruments described in [Brito and Pearl (2012)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1301.0560.pdf).

Causal graphs in convenient way introduce *mediation*. Lets look at the classical causal model for instrumental variable in terms of mediation:

[image]

Effect we want to identify is $\beta$, it is "true" effect of X on Y. As described in previous answer, it can not be identified directly, because of existence of unmeasured confounder C.

However we can understand it in a way, that X *mediates* effect of Z on Y.

In this setting effect Z on X is identified correctly, it is equal $\alpha$. Also, effect of Z on Y is identified correctly, it is equal $\alpha \cdot \beta$.

Therefore if we want to calculate $\beta$ we can simply divide estimator from the second model by estimator from the first model. The procedure would be similar, as in estimating the effect in front-door criterion.

What happens then in the 2SLS procedure? In my intuitive understanding we still estimate still effect of Z on Y, however it includes *already forced*, or *already included* $\alpha$ parameter. What is left in the second stage regression is only $\beta$.

---

Brito, Carlos, and Judea Pearl. "Generalized instrumental variables." arXiv preprint arXiv:1301.0560 (2012).

Comment: Hi: both of your answers were great but could either of you give a simple ( as possible ) example of Y, X and Z. Thanks. If  there's one in the paper by Brito and Pearl, then disregard my question. . I'm going to check that out now.

Comment: @mlofton One frequent example is price of tobacco products (Z) for the influence of smoking (X) on health/death (Y), possibly confounded by genetic factors (C).

Comment: i think this is one of most canonical examples: https://www.nber.org/system/files/working_papers/w4067/w4067.pdf And here is another: https://academic.oup.com/qje/article-abstract/106/4/979/1873496?redirectedFrom=fulltext

Comment: thanks phlpsgabler and cure. I will check out the links and learn something for sure.