In a doubly robust learner, do the covariates need to be the same for the outcome model and the propensity model?
In a doubly robust learner/estimator, do we need to use the same feature set X when creating the outcome model and the propensity model? Or could we use a subset of X for the propensity model or even completely different features all together?
From what I've read it seems like they use the same covariates but is that a hard and fast rule? Would anything be violated if I model them with separate features?

By Doubly Robust, do you mean a weighted regression model weighted by inverse propensity scores?

EDIT:  It seems I have mispoke.  The folklore is true: the best way to learn is to be wrong on the internet. Thanks to @pzivich for pointing me to some resources.
I was wrong about including instruments (predictors of the treatment, independent of the outcome) in the propensity score model.  Doing so will increase the MSE of the resulting estimate.  This paragraph from the discussion section of second paper pzivich mentions reads

This simulation study also revealed that if variables unrelated to the outcome but related to the exposure are added to a PS model they will increase the variance of an estimated exposure effect without decreasing its bias. Adding strong predictors of exposure to the PS model increases the variability of the estimated PS. If these added variables are unrelated to the outcome, then the variation they induce in the PS is not correcting confounding and is therefore only adding noise the estimated exposure effect. This result also suggests that there is little risk in adding a variable unrelated to exposure to a PS model. If the included covariate is unrelated to the outcome, it will affect neither the bias nor the variance of the estimator, but if it is related to the outcome, it can improve efficiency.

which I think is illustrative.

Do the variables need to be the same?  Not necessarily.
Propensity score models attempt to model the probability of treatment.  There may be variables in the propensity score model which are useful for estimating P(treated) but are not confounders.  So it isn't the case that all variables in the propensity model should be in the regression.
A similar argument can be made the other way.  There might be some variables which are not related to P(treat) but which can none the less explain variation in $Y$, hence resulting in an increase in precision.
What is most important from my understanding is that both models adjust for appropriate confounders.

You should not be adjusting for instruments (predictors of treatment but not the outcome) in the propensity score model. It can amplify bias https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/34172691/ Also adjusting for predictors of the outcome but not the treatment can improve precision when included in either the propensity score or outcome model https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1513192/ So these arguments don't hold.

@pzivich if I’ve read your first link correctly, the authors seem to argue that adjusting for instruments in a regression on the outcome can amplify bias. Does this bias still exist if the instrument is used in the propensity score model? I would think not since a) by virtue of being an instrument does not cause the treatment, and b) would not otherwise be correlated with the outcome else it would be a confounder.

The second paper reads “In contrast, including variables that are related to the exposure but not the outcome will decrease the precision of the estimated exposure effect without decreasing bias” which is also what I write here. It seems this paper is mostly arguing that precision is hurt when modelling for instruments — which is important. Have I read these correctly? If so I can edit my answer to reflect these.

In the 1st, the relevant part is Type 3 overadjustment bias, which is adjustment for an instrument of the exposure (Table 1) Essentially, it can cause unmeasured confounding to increase. This was observed in the 2nd paper, but was not something known. You can see this in their Table 1, where bias is worse for adjusting of X3 (the instrument) versus none (bias goes from 5.95 to 7.33 when adjusting for X3). Since this was not well-known, their language is a bit soft. Recommendations are a bit different, see conclusions of https://academic.oup.com/aje/article/174/11/1223/111637

@pzivich I see that now.  Very interesting, thanks for pointing that out

Happy to help :) this is one of those weird results that I know the history of

Showed here analytically why controlling for an instrument amplifies bias https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/641088/instrumental-variable-as-a-control-variable/641568#641568

@Jonathan That example is easier to believe since treatment would be on the path from Instrument -> outcome.  That adjusting for an instrument in the propensity score model results in bias is more surprising to me.

Why would adjustment for an instrument by regression versus propensity score make a difference? Both would remove exogenous variation in the treatment, wouldn’t they?
